# To determine size of each column in csv table

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to read a pair of columns from csv files and want know the size of each column in each individual pair.

I have tried the attached code. It throws following errors:
(1) String could not be converted to float, whenever it sees blank cells
(2) IndexError, if the first pair to be read is of smaller size then the rest.
Basically, len(table) gives the maximum number of rows in the table. Or am I missing something here.

```
  x1        y1         x2       y2
0.0031  0.01527   -0.41973  0.01237
0.30568 0.08478   -0.07486  0.16463
0.4986  0.26355    0.0097   0.44943
0.61884 0.5102     0.30568  0.83218
0.75758 0.90136   0.62544   0.98121
1.02977 0.96214    


# Save above data to file temp.csv (strip-off the first row) and the  try to 
# read by following code

infile = open("temp.csv", 'r')
table = []
for row in csv.reader(infile):
  table.append(row)
infile.close() # better leave that file alone.
for r in range (0, len(table)):
    for c in range(0, len(table[r])):
        table[r][c] = float(table[r][c])
```

## The float() will give error :ValueError: could not convert string to float for the second set of data.

I want to know the size of each individual pairs when all pairs in csv tables are not of the same size.